# draw graph and set edge transparency in networkx

Tags: graph, networkx, transparency, node-centrality

I'm tring draw a graph in networkx and at the same time, calculate edge betweenness centrality of every edge, using this to set a different transparency for each edge.
My code looks like this：

```
G = nx.gnp_random_graph(10,0.5) 

options = {
    'node_color':'black',
    'node_size':1,
    'alpha':0.2
}

edge_betweenness_centrality(G)

nx.draw(G,**options)
plt.show()
```

Where the first line is to generate a random graph with 10 nodes, and the `edge_betweenness_centrality(G)` calculate edge betweenness of every edge.The output just like this:
[the output of edge_betweenness_centrality(G)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjamP.png)

And what I want to do is set the transparency of every edge using the above output. I can only set the unity transparency in options just like the above code `'alpha':0.2`. So,how do I achieve that?

Can someone help me? I will be very grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `alpha` value in `nx.draw_network_edges` can only be a float and not a list or dictionnary (doc [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html)), you will probably have to loop through your edges and draw each edge seperately. You can specify the edge in the `edgelist` argument and change the `alpha` value iteratively.

See code below:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

G = nx.gnp_random_graph(10,0.5) 

options = {
    'node_color':'black',
    'node_size':200
}

cent=nx.edge_betweenness_centrality(G)
node_pos=nx.circular_layout(G) #Any layout will work here, including nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos=node_pos,**options)#draw nodes
[nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos=node_pos,edgelist=[key],alpha=np.amin([value*10,1]),width=5) for key,value in cent.items()] #loop through edges and draw them

plt.show()
```

And the output gives:

[image]

Comment: But I also have a question when I code like this: [my code](https://github.com/catbao/test2/blob/main/c3900c5d29bc6b0f8d4753e71c3b662.jpg)  The result is like this: [the result](https://github.com/catbao/test2/blob/main/f025e41fdc37761d401931cff5896f2.jpg).     It looks like the edges and the vertices are separate. Why this appear? How can I solve it?

Comment: It looks like only circular_layout works? And if I use spring_layout, it will be that case.

Comment: It should work with all possible layouts. You just need to make sure that you pass the same node positions to `nx.draw_networkx_nodes` and `nx.draw_networkx_edges` .  `nx.spring_layout` has some randomness associated to it (`nx.circular_layout` doesn't). Which means that calling it twice will output two different layouts. It's best to store the node positions in a variable and then pass it to the two drawing functions. See edit of my answer for more details.